# lenovo ideapad 14ISK 300 lost wifi connection ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, lenovo

I can connect to wifi when I boot the 300 14ISK, however, after a while the wifi connection will lost, and I cannot see the same ssid of the router.

Please help.

Output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8821]
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:a814]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: I had a similar issue. Changing from unity to gnome helped me.

Comment: Also having this issue with the ideapad 310

Answer (score -1):

Try upgrading the distribution to Ubuntu 16.04.1. 
[I've had a similar situation - with a new Lenovo Ideapad 14ISK Computer Model - where I couldn't connect to Wi-Fi on account of the fact that I had (Xubuntu) 14.04 and should have upgraded to/downloaded (Ubuntu) 16.04.1 in order to have 
Wi-Fi Connection]. 
Good Luck.

Comment: Do you have the same wireless adapter?

Comment: I haven't found an indication for my Wireless Adapter after typing this command, but I presume that by doing what I suggested, It'll work, because - based on my experience - the Lenovo 14ISK Computer Model doesn't support older versions of Linux, hence the need to upgrade to the latest in order to get things to work properly. (My assumption).

Comment: If it is not related to the OP's wireles adapter, the answer is not helpful. Same laptop models may have different adapters.